# Random points in a space time

Tags: r, random, coordinates

I have a set of date compost by several years of mortality in the roads. My data are coordinates x&y. I need to create a random distribution of data as a control to be able to compare my data with the random control and see if there are hot-spots of mortality. I know it is possible to create a random set of points with R, but I don’t know how to make both comparable in terms of time. How can I crate these points for a period of several years?

Thank you again

Aurora

Comment: In general the `runif`, `rexp`, `rnorm` etc. functions are there for building random data in R. Check out those functions. You can get help by typing eg. `?runif` in the console

Comment: Welcome to SO! In this community, it's easier to be helped if you can post some data as example, show your attempts and [so on](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Here you should use `poisson` distribution to generate the sample data.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I’ll try all of that and I’ll come back to you to see if I manged to do it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify hot spots it is better to use [2D kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation). Please see below the example for road-kill mortality from [data portal for the State of Washington](https://data.wa.gov/). To identify hot spots `contour` plot and `kde2d` function were used. Please see the code below:

```
library(lubridate)
mort <- read.csv("https://data.wa.gov/api/views/mcp7-tcwf/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ll <- t(sapply(mort$Location, function(x) na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\(|\\,| |\\)"))))))
rownames(ll) <- NULL
colnames(ll) <- c("lat", "lon")
mort2 <- cbind(mort, ll)
mort2$Salvage.Date.Time2 <- mdy_hms(mort2$Salvage.Date.Time)
mort2$month <- month(mort2$Salvage.Date.Time2)
mort2$year <- year(mort2$Salvage.Date.Time2)
mort2 <- mort2[mort2$year> 2016, ]

mort3 <- mort2[with(mort2, lat > 45.5 & lat < 49.& lon > -125 & lon < -116), ]
f1 <- with(mort3, kde2d(lat, lon, n = 100))

plot(mort3$lat, mort3$lon, pch = 18, col = "lightblue")
contour(f1, levels  =  c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2), add = TRUE, labcex = 1)
```

Output:
[image: plots]